# Search box with Ruby Shoes

Tags: ruby, regex, shoes

I have a short script that uses regular expressions to search a file for a specific phrase that a user types in. Basically, it's a simple search box.

I'm now trying to make this search box have a GUI, so that users are able to type into a box, and have their matches 'alerted' to them.

I'm new to using ruby shoes in any great detail, and have been using the examples on TheShoeBox website.

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong with my code?

Here is my command line version that works:

```
string = File.read('db.txt')
puts "Enter what you're looking for below"


begin
while(true)
  break if string.empty? 
  print "Search> "; STDOUT.flush; phrase = gets.chop
  break if phrase.empty?
  names = string.split(/\n/)
  matches = names.select { |name| name[/#{phrase}/i] } 
  puts "\n \n"
  puts matches
  puts "\n \n"

   end
end
```

Here is my attempt at using it within Ruby Shoes:

```
Shoes.app :title => "Search v0.1", :width => 300, :height => 150 do

string = File.read('db.txt')

    names = string.split(/\n/)
    matches = names.select { |name| name[/#{phrase}/i] } 


def search(text)
    text.tr! "A-Za-z", "N-ZA-Mn-za-m"
end

@usage = <<USAGE
     Search - This will search for the inputted text within the database
USAGE

stack :margin => 10 do 
    para @usage
    @input = edit_box :width => 200
end

flow :margin => 10 do
    button('Search') { @output.matches }

end
    stack(:margin => 0) { @output = para }
end
```

Many thanks

Comment: So, just make sure that it's all ok with this code. For example, `phrase` never declared but you use it in this code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, the first code bit can be neatened up.

```
file = File.open 'db.txt', 'rb'
puts "Enter (regex) search term or quit:"

exit 1 unless file.size > 0
loop do
  puts
  print "query> "
  redo if ( query = gets.chomp ).empty?
  exit 0 if query == "quit"
  file.each_line do |line|
    puts "#{file.lineno}: #{line}" if line =~ /#{query}/i
  end
  file.rewind
end
```

The `rb` option lets it work as expected in Windows (especially with Shoes, you should try and be platform-independent). `chomp` strips off `\r\n` and `\n` but not `a` for example, while `chop` just blindly takes off the last character. `loop do end` is nicer than `while true`. Also why store matches in a variable? Just read through the file line by line (which allows for CRLF endings) as opposed to splitting by `\n` although the residual `\r` wouldn't really pose much of a problem...

As for the Shoes bit:

```
Shoes.app :title => "Search v0.2", :width => 500, :height => 600 do

  @file = File.open 'db.txt', 'rb'

  def search( file, query )
    file.rewind
    file.select {|line| line =~ /#{query}/i }.map {|match| match.chomp }
  end

  stack :margin => 10 do
    @input  = edit_line :width => 400

    button "search" do
      matches = search( @file, @input.text )
      @output.clear
      @output.append do
        matches.empty? ?
          title( "Nothing found :(" ) :
          title( "Results\n" )
      end
      matches.each do |match|
        @output.append { para match }
      end
    end

    @output = stack { title "Search for something." }

  end

end
```

You never defined `@output.matches` or called your `search()` method. See if it makes sense now.